# Information on new fields TFRecord format for Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I was digging through the [TfExampleDecoder](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py) and saw some fields that don't appear to be documented anywhere. Starting in line 207:

`fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_group_of: (slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/group_of')),
fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_weights: (slim_example_decoder.Tensor('image/object/weight')),`

Is there documentation for the purpose that these serve?

Answer (score 0):

fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_weights is *most likely* a weight that gets multiplied with the loss. See 3.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf